# Excel file has disappeared from sharepoint document library

Tags: sharepoint

Two days ago an excel came up missing from a document library. This document library only had this file and nows it's gone. When I go to All Site Content->Document Librarys it shows that there is still one file in the library. Seems like there is something screwy.

Is there anything I can do to get this item to reappear?

MOSS2007
Recycle: Must be default never changed anything and really don't know how to find the settings for this

Document Library Settings
Versioning Settings:
  content approval: no
  document version history: create major versions
  require check out: yes

Comment: Could you let me know what version of SharePoint you are running and what are the Recycle Bin and Versioning setttings you have set?

Answer (score 1):

The file has probably been checked out by someone (particularly since the Doc library is set to force this), which in many circumstances hides the file from everyone else till the file is checked back in again.

You can manage checked out files via the Document Library settings page - as an admin you can force the files back to checked in, although you might want to check with the person who has it checked out that this is appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely try the site's Recycle Bin (located on the quick launch bar), and if it's not in there, try the site collection Recycle Bin (you'll need to go into the Site Settings for the top level site).